# Can two variables' entropies be equal, as well as their joint entropy?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same Shannon entropy, $$H(X) = H(Y)$$
can their joint entropy ever be equal to both? $$H(X,Y) = H(X) = H(Y)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have an example here. (I'm still learning MathJax, so hope this is clear enough).

Consider the following 3x3 matrix that represents the joint probability from the intersection of two distributions.
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    & y_i & y_j & y_k & H(X) \\
    x_i& 0.333 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.528\\
    x_j& 0.000 & 0.333 & 0.000 & 0.528\\
    x_k& 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.333 & 0.528\\
    H(Y) & 0.528 & 0.528 & 0.528 & 1.585\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

As can be seen, the marginal entropies, $\mathit{H(X)}$ (rows) and $\mathit{H(Y)}$ (cols), are both equal to 1.585. The joint entropy, $\mathit{H(X,Y)}$, by my calculations, equals 1.585 as well.  In this case, the mutual information, $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$, is also equal to 1.585. This agrees with the following identity:

$$\mathit{I(X;Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)}$$
$${1.585=1.585+1.585-1.585}$$

This occurs when all the information conveyed by $\mathit{X}$ is shared with $\mathit{Y}$.

Comment: could you unravel this to the 2 data series' non-joint probabilities please so i can calculate everything as well?

Comment: @develarist. I have a spreadsheet here that I use for my modelling with the full calculations but not sure how I can present them here. I will see what I can do.

Comment: even a small dataset of 10 observations (probabilities) for two variables $X$ and $Y$ would do

Comment: @ develarist. Sorry for the delay in replying. Consider the paired results (ordered) for the before test $\mathit{(X)}$ and after test $\mathit{(Y)}$ where $\mathit{X}$ = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3} and $\mathit{Y}$ = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3}. For this example, $\mathit{X = Y}$.  The distributions are uniform and the joint probability matrix is given above where the indexes relate to $\mathit{i}$ = 1, $\mathit{j}$ = 2 and $\mathit{k}$ = 3.  It follows that $\mathit{H(X) = H(Y) = H(X,Y) = I(X;Y) = 1.585}$.

Comment: How about a case where $X\neq Y$?

Comment: @ develarist An alternative premise - still ordered - is $\mathit{X}$ = {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3} and $\mathit{Y}$ = {3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1}. Here,  $\mathit{X ≠ Y}$. The distributions remain uniform and still $\mathit{H(X) = H(Y) = H(X,Y) = I(X;Y) = 1.585}$.

Comment: That obviously doesn't change anything since entropy is permutation invariant

Comment: Yes, true, but both example do provide evidence to prove your initial question that there are at least two situations where $\mathit{H(X) = H(Y) = H(X,Y)}$

Comment: For discrete random variables ok, but this scenario is not likely to happen for continuous r.v.s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112903/discussion-between-murray-b-and-develarist).